# Panda histogram throwing type error

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns, of which the first contains some strings but the second and third are floats only. An yet, when I try to plot a histogram of values in the third column, I am getting a type error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

I don't really understand how this is coming up... Quite a few of my values are negative, is it seeing the '-' as a string? That would be completely ridiculous, as the frame is read directly from a csv file...[image]

Comment: what does `df.info()` output, also don't post images. Additionally it looks to me like all the types are strings as I see no max and min values in your output from `describe`. You need to post raw data, or a link to your data, and your code that you used to read the csv into your df

Comment: It's not the `.hist` method that's throwing the error; it's the `.diff` method. Try coercing the Series as a float first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `.describe()` shows, `IAR.regCoeff` is in fact something like strings, not numbers. Try

```
IAR.regCoeff = IAR.regCoeff.astype(float)
```

Comment: Ah, it worked! Thank you very much :)
Just out of curiosity, why was it read as string? Just because of the number of decimals?

Comment: It is impossible to answer why was it read like this without knowing how did you read it. I suggest to post another question and provide code snippet that shows how did you create this dataframe.

Comment: Note that you can check the datatype of a Series just by printing it: the last line may look like `Name: IAR, dtype: object`.

Comment: (For a serie, `s.dtype, for a dataframe `df.dtypes`)